# How to add a countdown timer to an array based off mysql date/timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm looking at changing an expiry date from datatables into a countdown timer. I would like $row["expiry"] to show the countdown timer instead of just the static date/time stamp.

At the moment it uses ajax to call a php file which gets the mysql results and puts it into an array for datatables. I'm not really sure where to begin with changing a date/time stamp into a countdown timer.

**Expiry output:**

```
2019-01-27 09:53
```

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){

  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "paging": false,
    "bFilter": false
    "order" : [],
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "Empty Table!"
    },
    "ajax" : {
     url:"get.php",
     type:"POST"
    }
   });
  }


</script>
```

**get.php**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = '<div class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="name">' . $row["name"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="comments">' . $row["comments"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="expiry">' . $row["expiry"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete Item</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just display the difference, in seconds, between now and the expiration date?

Comment: that would work but I'm not too sure how to implement it properly ):

Answer (score 0):

You can replace 
`$row["expiry"]` with `abs(strtotime($row["expiry"]) - strtotime(time()))`
 that will solve issue.

Comment: How would I turn that value into a countdown?

Comment: @BreezeCrunch i don't understand, this.solution will give you countdown in seconds , are you looking for real time countdown timer that keeps decrementing.

Comment: Yes. I would like to turn the output of expiry which was originally 2019-01-27 09:53  into a real time count down that goes down per minute.I had a play around with some JS and converting it the way you said but I can't wrap my head around it ):

Comment: @BreezeCrunch Then i think you can call the get.php first time and then get initial counts and then set up timers in frontend which will go on decrementing --- setTimeout( () => {$("row-selectors").innerHTML = $("row-selectors").innerHTML-1}, 1000);

Comment: I decided to do  $deltaTimeServer = strtotime($expire)-time(); and place the deltaTimeServer into the div. How I would I do the javascript processing of the time to make it countdown? I tried another example of  this.timestamp = parseInt(this.firstChild.nodeValue,10); but it doesn't correctly parse it.

Comment: @BreezeCrunch  You can add an id to HTML part and do something like this setInterval(() => {$('#id').innerHTML--},1000)

Comment: Sorry i used setTimeout instead of setInterval